# What is the name of the ash particles?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

What do you call those ash particles flying out of a fire? [image]

Comment: They're called voldemortlets.  We don't have a specific name for them.

Comment: a **mote** or a **speck** of dust

Comment: As you said, why not just call it "ash"?

Comment: There's not many HP fans 'ere? +1 to TRomano's comment.

Answer (score 1):

I call them sparks. Motes or specks would more commonly refer to particles of dust.